# Edit Facebook Page Info using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I want to edit Facebook page info using Graph API. Every time I update on my website, I want automate update info of my Facebook Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post a status message on a Page by issuing an HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/feed with the publish_stream and manage_pages permissions and the following parameters.

```
Parameter   Description            Type     Required
message     Status Message content string   yes
```

Comment: I want to edit page name, website, address, or description some thing like that.